# C++ pointer, output

Tags: c++, visual-c++, output

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    float x[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    float *zeiger = x + 1;
    cout << zeiger << endl;
    cout << *(zeiger + 2) << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        zeiger += i;
        x[i] = pow(*zeiger, -1);
        cout << x[i] << endl;
    };
    system("PAUSE");
};
```

Hello guys.
Can someone tell me why the program gives out 0,2 at the end?
I understand the previous outputs:
address
4
0,5
0,33

But why 0,2 then? Shouldn't it be 0,25? (Sorry if my english isn't to your liking. Still learning :) )

Comment: I suggest you draw the array and the pointers on paper, using arrows for the pointers. Then [rubber duck debug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) the program, erasing and redrawing the arrows (pointers) on the paper.

Comment: It could also help to know that for *any* pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `p[i]` is *exactly* equal to `*(p + i)`. That leads to e.g. `*zeiger` being equal to `zeiger[0]`.

Comment: Notice `zeiger += i;`, not `zeiger += 1;`.

Comment: `zeiger += i;` By doing that, you read/modify memory outside array `x`. Maybe use `zeiger ++`.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Now I got it. Didn't realize that zeiger gets overwritten when using += i. Thank you guys :)